# as3 air and screen size dection issue on devices

Tags: android, actionscript-3, actionscript, air, resize

I have worked so hard on an app that displays perfectly on my Galaxy Note 3. However, it does not display right on iPhone and also one other Droid I tested on. My issue is with addChild() and then resizing it to fit the screen. For some reason when I add the Background (addBG(); The screen size works but if I load addChild to the BG, this works great on my Note 3 but not on the iPhone or another android device.

My issue is with the screenX, screenY var I created. They seem to be different for devices. Or it is a "rendering order issue" I am not sure. Would be so greatful for the help to fix this issue so it looks great on each phone. I have read some tuts on this subject but they are confusing. I think my code is close, I hope, and maybe it just needs a tweak. !

Here is a shot of the about screen on an IPhone. See the white does not fit the whole screen. [image]

and Here is a shot from my Droid Note 3. [image]

Declared Vars in a package:

This is not my full code, of course but only that which I believe is relevant.

```
public var screenX:int;
public var screenY:int;


   public function Main()
    {
        if (stage)
        {

            setStage();
            addBG();    
        }
    }

    public function setStage()
    {
        stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
        stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;

        if (flash.system.Capabilities.screenResolutionX > stage.stageWidth)
        {
            screenX = stage.stageWidth;
            screenY = stage.stageHeight;
        }
        else
        {
            screenX = flash.system.Capabilities.screenResolutionX;
            screenY = flash.system.Capabilities.screenResolutionY;
        }
    }
```

This works: addBG();

```
            public function addBG()
    {
        theBG = new BG();
        addChild(theBG);
        theBG.width = screenX;
        theBG.height = screenY;
    }
```

This does not: addAbout();

```
public function addAbout()
        {

            About = new viewAbout();
            About.width = screenX;
            About.height = screenY;
            theBG.addChild(About);
            TweenMax.fromTo(About,1, {alpha:0}, {alpha:1, ease:Expo.easeOut}  );

        }
```

UPDATE: And yet another more complex load is also called from a button and having the same issue. I hope you see the logic of what I am trying to do. First set the BG to the device then load and resize content to fit proportionally into the BG I loaded. The reason being, the BG will be distorted to different proportions and that's ok, but the content can not. So here is the example that loads content into the BG and then content into that container.

```
public function addRosaryApp()
        {
            Rosary = new viewRosaryApp();
            Rosary.width = screenX;
            Rosary.height = screenY;
            theBG.addChild(Rosary);
            TweenMax.fromTo(Rosary,1, {alpha:0}, {alpha:1, ease:Expo.easeOut}  );

            contentRosary = new contentRosaryApp();
            theBG.addChild(contentRosary);
            contentRosary.width = screenX;
            contentRosary.scaleY = contentRosary.scaleX;
            contentRosary.x = screenX/2 - contentRosary.width/2;
            contentRosary.y = menuBanner.height;    
        }
```

Comment: Are you getting the correct values for iphone if you trace your screenX/screenY?

Comment: Yes, its like 600 by 900 or something I forget. Its an iphone 4s. It is working for the BG and fits it niecly to screen. So maybe its a loading issue I am thinking or the iPhone is not always seeing the values of screenX and ScreenY

Comment: You should use stage.fullscreenWidth, fullscreenHeight. Does it make any difference?

Comment: I will try. :) And get back to you.

Comment: The load about worked but I added more examples above because I also need to load content on the page and this can not be stretched. It seems the screenX is still not working. :(

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding the child to stage first, and then setting the size? That's the only difference I can see between addBG and addAbout

```
        About = new viewAbout();
        theBG.addChild(About); // do this first
        About.width = screenX; // then set width 
        About.height = screenY; // and height
```

Comment: I think you are on to something. I noticed that it is being scaled because the content is being scaled. So if its squeezed, the newly added content will also be squeezed. To fix it I think I can simply do a addChild(menuBanner); over the top, and not add the content inside the BG, which is what I really need. My question is, if I do that will I be adding a new instance or will I simply be moving it to the top, which is what I want?

Comment: iF it is the same variable, it will 'move' it... meaning, it will "reparent" it. However, if it is still attached to another parent, it will throw an exception so you will need to handle it safely

Comment: ok that should work then. However, if I did need it I don't know how to handle it safely.

Comment: you could do something along the lines of; `if(menuBanner.parent != null){menuBanner.parent.removeChild(menuBanner);} xxxxxx.addChild(menuBanner);`

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem may have to do with either of several things.
My findings so far from my own devices (an Ipad Air, an iphone 4S, an LG G2 and an Acer Iconia A500) is that the only device size that's being reported correctly at all times is the *stage.fullScreenWidth* and the *stage.fullScreenHeight*

1st, Android reports *Capabilities.screenResolutionX* as the LONG side of your Android device.
IOS devices however report the SHORT side of your device to *Capabilities.screenResolutionX*.

2nd, stage.stageWidth and stage.stageHeight seem to report the wrong size on both Android and IOS. 
And in fact if you check these **before** and **after** setting *stage.scaleMode* and *stage.align* then the values will differ completly (although Android will show it almost correctly).

My suggestion is that you set a base size (width and height) for your app and then compare it with the actual stage.fullScreenWidth and stage.fullScreenHeight reported by the device. That way you can get some nice scaleratios to use to scale your displayobjects. That's what I'm currently on my apps and it scales just fine :-)